# How to switch called php page using AJAX in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an several online application forms built into a (they differ per country) and I need to switch from one to the other with a users button click.

The code I have does this however it also produces a 500 error which breaks any other scripts.

Can anyone give me an idea of what I am doing wrong?

```
    //Update appURL
if (jQuery('button[id="ukApp"]').hasClass( "checked" )) {   
    appURL = "wp-content/plugins/GoMarkets_application/uk/uk-application.php";  
} else if (jQuery('button[id="itlApp"]').hasClass( "checked" )) {       
    appURL = "wp-content/plugins/GoMarkets_application/itl/it-application.php"; 
} 

//Get URL path
function getContextPath() {
    var ctx = window.location.pathname,
        path = '/' !== ctx ? ctx.substring(0, ctx.indexOf('/', 1) + 1) : ctx;
    return path + (/\/$/.test(path) ? '' : '/');
}

//Country Application URL

function getOutput() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: getContextPath() + appURL,
      complete: function (response) {
          jQuery('#output').html(response.responseText);
      },
      error: function () {
          jQuery('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
      }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: if you're receiving an error 500, the server log should give you a more detailed error.

Comment: the js code above is useless until you find out what the actual error is, so yes... go look at the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

here is your ajax function

```
$.ajax({
 url: ajax.url,
 ...
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(response) {
  $('#myDiv').html(response.html);
 },
})
```

and the php function

```
function my_ajax_load() {
 $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

 ob_start(); 
 include(locate_template('my-template-file.php',false,false));  
 $page_template = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
 $response['html'] = $page_template;
 wp_send_json($response);

}
```

in your template file you can use your variables declared in the function, in this example you can you `$post_id` inside the `my-template-file.php`

For example:

```
<?php /* Template name: My template */ 
 if($post_id) {
  echo get_the_title($post_id);
 }
?>
```

500 error is caused by php error not ajax or jquery, check out your template file for a php errors

Answer (score 0):

There was a missing image being called by the page I was trying to load, the error only showed up in the logs.  Thanks all :)